# How to write cheerio query for HTML structure?

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

My cheerio code snippet is below. I'm trying to obtain the name of the item in the `<td>` tag, and grab the numbers inside the subsequent td tags (1,2,1).

The itemName query works, but the startPrice, endPrice, and difPrice queries do not. Where is the flaw in my logic, or is it a syntactic error?

```js
var $ = cheerio.load(html);

//
$('.table-item-link').each(function(i, element) {
    var itemName = ($(this).attr('title');
    console.log(itemName);
});

//Iterate through all tr inside div = 'content'
$('.content tr').each(function(i, element) {
    var startPrice = $(this).children()[2].children()[0].text();
    var endPrice = $(this).children()[3].children()[0].text();
    var difPrice = $(this).children()[4].children()[0].text();
    console.log(price)
});
```

```html
<div class='content'>
    <table>
        <thead>
             <tr>Table Title</tr>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td>
                   <a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Jangerberry_seed/viewitem?obj=5104" title="Jangerberry seed" class='table-item-link'>
            <img src='http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/5125_obj_sprite.gif?id=5104' alt="Jangerberry seed"><span>Jangerberry seed</span>
           </a>
                   </td>
                 <td class='memberItem'><img src='http://www.runescape.com/img/rs3/grand_exchange/tick.png' title="Members Only" alt="Yes" /></td>
           <td><a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Oak_toy_box/viewitem?obj=9849">1</a></td>
           <td><a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Oak_toy_box/viewitem?obj=9849">2</a></td>
           <td><a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Oak_toy_box/viewitem?obj=9849">1</a></td>
             <td class='change positive'><a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Oak_toy_box/viewitem?obj=9849">+100%</a></td>
         </tr>
               <****repeat a bunch of tr w/ same format as above****>
               <****close all other tags****************************>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I reviewed you code. Why not to go with just

```
var arr = [];
$(".content tr a").each(function (i, elem) {
  var a = $(elem);
  var text = a.text().trim().toLowerCase();
  arr.push(text);
});
```

You also can filter by `i` value like if `i !== 2, i !== 3`